# Ho do I disallow urls for specific countries in robots.txt file?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I have multi-site in WordPress and have a setup like this

`domain.com (main version for Australia)`
`domain.com/us`
`domain.com/eu`
`...`

I want if Australian users to search on google, which should only show the main URL domain.com and if someone in USA and Canada searches, only domain.com/us should appear in google search results, similarly, all Europeans, should be able to see domain.com/eu version only.

What can be the best optimal approach?

Thanks.

Currently, I'm using a redirection plugin which I think blocks all the URLs to crawl on google. So, figured out that maybe the robots.txt file could fix the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually I haven't done any code yet, but just assuming there will be a solution to achieve the goal which I have mentioned above.